# How Do I Read This Hole Error

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I am trying to write an implementation of flatMap. But this is inconsequential, I'm really interested in understanding the error message. But for context so far I have:

```
flatMap ::
(a -> List b)
  -> List a
  -> List b
flatMap f xs = foldRight undefined undefined _undefined
```

This gives the following error for the type hole:

```
Found hole ‘_undefined’ with type: List a0
    Where: ‘a0’ is an ambiguous type variable
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: List a (bound at src/Course/List.hs:266:11)
      f :: a -> List b (bound at src/Course/List.hs:266:9)
      flatMap :: (a -> List b) -> List a -> List b
        (bound at src/Course/List.hs:266:1)
    In the third argument of ‘foldRight’, namely ‘_undefined’
    In the expression: foldRight undefined undefined _undefined
    In an equation for ‘flatMap’:
        flatMap f xs = foldRight undefined undefined _undefined
```

I know the right peg for this hole is xs, but I dont understand why the haskell compiler has given it a type denoted List a0 and how that relates to the type I'm going to use of List a?

I think it has something to do with the fact that the whole could take a superset of the type List a or something? by why then didn't it just call it List b instead of specifically List a0.

Cheers,
Jim

Comment: It has to do with the type of `foldRight`, specifically, that it expects a list as its third argument.  `a0` is just another variable name, it might as well have been called `b`.  Supertypes and subtypes are not in Haskell's type system.

Comment: Cheers @luqui that's what I was wondering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly, the compiler infers types as follows.

Let's give to each `undefined` a distinct type unknown:

```
flatMap :: (a -> List b) -> List a -> List b
flatMap f xs =
   foldRight (undefined :: a1) (undefined :: b1) (_undefined :: c1)
```

Now, `foldRight` expects a binary function having a type like `a2 -> b2 -> b2`, so let's make `a1` more precise.

```
flatMap :: (a -> List b) -> List a -> List b
flatMap f xs =
   foldRight (undefined :: a2 -> b2 -> b2) (undefined :: b1) (_undefined :: c1)
```

Now, `foldRight` requires that the second `undefined` has type `b1 ~ b2`, while the last one must have type `c1 ~ List a2`.

```
flatMap :: (a -> List b) -> List a -> List b
flatMap f xs =
   foldRight (undefined :: a2 -> b2 -> b2) (undefined :: b2) (_undefined :: List a2)
```

(assuming we have `Nil` and `Cons` as constructors of your `List` type)

The result of `foldRight` is `b2`, but the type signatures says this is actually `List b`. Hence,

```
flatMap :: (a -> List b) -> List a -> List b
flatMap f xs =
   foldRight (undefined :: a2 -> List b -> List b) (undefined :: List b)
             (_undefined :: List a2)
```

Now we are done. Note that there are no constraints which can allow us to deduce that `a2 ~ a`, so `a2` remains an unknown, and the compiler cannot suggest a more precise type for it, and your hole generates the GHC message you posted.

More concretely, look at this specialization where `a2 ~ Int`:

```
flatMap :: (a -> List b) -> List a -> List b
flatMap f xs =
   foldRight (g :: Int -> List b -> List b) (Nil :: List b) (Cons 3 Nil :: List Int)
   where g :: Int -> List b -> List b
         g y ys = ys
```

The above type checks, even if we chose `a2 ~ Int` instead of `a2 ~ a`. Hence the compiler cannot infer `a2 ~ a`, since there are more solutions to the type unknown `a2`.